# Komar mass for vacuum solutions

Tags: general-relativity, mass, vacuum

I'm a little confused about the integral definition of the Komar mass, and how it gives the correct result for vacuum solutions.

As given by Poisson, the Komar mass is
$$
M_{Komar} = \int \left(2T_{\alpha\beta} - T g_{\alpha\beta}\right)n^\alpha\xi^\beta_{(t)}\sqrt{h}d^3y,
$$
where $n^a$ and $\xi^\beta_{(t)}$ are the normal vectors and timelike killing vectors, respectively, and $\sqrt{h}d^3y$ is the volume element of the hypersurface induced from the chosen slicing.

The thing I don't get is that in a vacuum solution, like Schwarzschild, $T_{\alpha\beta} = 0$, right?  So I don't see how the volume integral could ever give you $M_{Komar} = m$.

Comment: I think you want to use the surface-integral formulation of the Komar mass to avoid dealing with a volume integral that includes a singularity.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my question is why the surface-integral formulation is equivalent to this.  I can follow the derivation that says it is, but then interpreting the volume integral definition gives rise to this apparent paradox.  That is, when you derive the schwarzshild solution, you assume T=0, but I suppose that's only valid "outside" the singularity? (using a loose definition of "outside")

Comment: For the Schwarzschild metric $R^{\mu\nu}$ and thus $T^{\mu\nu}$ are zero for $r>0$.

Comment: Right, but then I'm confused about how that returns the correct mass for the above definition

Comment: Because they are singular at $r=0$. I don’t know whether there is a way to say “how infinite” they are there to make the volume integral work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komar integrals are based on the concept of covariant conservation laws associated with every infinitesimal coordinate transformation. If we have a current as $J_i^\mu  = \xi _\nu ^{(i)}{R^{\mu \nu }}$ associated with the Killing vector field $\xi _\nu ^{(i)}$ (which is conserved, ${\nabla _\mu }J_{(i)}^\mu  = 0$), we can find a conserved charge associated with that current as (see Carroll, pages 248-254)
$$
Q[{\xi _{(i)}}] = \frac{1}{{4\pi G}}\int {{d^3}\vec y\sqrt h {{\hat n}_\mu }J_{(i)}^\mu } .
$$
Using the Einstein field equations (${R_{\mu \nu }} - \frac{1}{2}{g_{\mu \nu }}R = \kappa {T_{\mu \nu }}$), the above formula may be written as
$$
Q[{\xi _i}] = \int {{d^3}\vec y\sqrt h {{\hat n}_\mu }\xi _\nu ^{(i)}\left( {2{T^{\mu \nu }} - {g^{\mu \nu }}T} \right)},
$$
which is the volume-integral formulation that you mentioned. But, there is a singularity at $r=0$ which renders the both integrals difficult to evaluate. Clearly, this is ill-defined for the Schwarzschild metric at $r=0$, so one cannot calculate the volume integral. In addition, outside of the singularity we have $R=T=0$. This is a common question and, despite of several proposals in order to resolve this problem (see Carroll, pages 248-254), we don't know quite how to deal with it in a complete, satisfactory way. But, we can still convert the volume integral to a surface integral without singularity using the Stokes' theorem, yielding
$$
Q[{\xi _i}] = \frac{1}{{4\pi G}}\int {{d^2}\vec y\sqrt h {{\hat n}_\mu }{{\hat u}_\nu }{\nabla ^\mu }\xi _{(i)}^\nu }.
$$
Seemingly, in the case of Schwarzschild spacetime, one has to use this form of Komar integral mass. However, some authors, including Wald in pages 289-291 of his great book, consider this definition (surface-integral formulation) as a fully satisfactory notion of the total mass in stationary, asymptotically flat spacetimes.Having this relation, you can easily find the correct answer as
$$
M[{\xi _t}] = \frac{1}{{4\pi G}}\int {{d^2}\vec y\sqrt h {{\hat n}_\mu }{{\hat u}_\nu }{\nabla ^\mu }\xi _{(t)}^\nu }
= \frac{1}{{4\pi G}}\int {{d^2}\vec y({r^2}\sin \theta ){g^{00}}\Gamma _{00}^1\xi _{(t)}^0}
= M\,
$$
We know this definition is true since it can be proved by use of the other well-known methods such as ADM approach, evaluating Euclidean partition function and also Brown-York formalism. Carroll has an interesting idea about the validity of the surface-Komar integral:
*''The point is that, since 6.38 [i.e., the above relation in this note] involves contributions only at spatial infinity, it should be a valid expression for the energy no matter what happens in the interior. ''*

So, if there exists an asymptotically timelike Killing vector, the total energy of a stationary spacetime (with flat or AdS asymptote) is obtained via surface-Komar integral.

Comment: hey, I'm seeing this response months late, but thank you very much! that's a great explanation

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I love this question and there's a really interesting answer.

If you have an actual planet, like earth, then $T_{\mu \nu}$ won't be $0$ because of the matter of the planet. So in that case, it makes sense.

But in Schwarzschild, there is no $T_{\mu \nu}$. People sometimes say that it blows up at the singularity. But this does not resolve the paradox, and is actually irrelevant. Look at a Penrose diagram for Schwarzschild spacetime. The singularities are in the past/future. They are not on a 3 dimensional time slice you would integrate over to calculate Komar mass.

In fact, the Schwarzschild spacetime really describes a wormhole between *two different* universes, and this resolve the paradox. You see, the time vector $\partial_t$ points "up" in our universe and "down" in the other universe! So if you really integrate over the full time slice, they cancel out!

Comment: Hi. This is interesting. I'm interested in learning more about this. Do you know a book/paper that discusses this in detail?

Comment: What is the physical meaning of the time vector pointing from up to down in the other universe when the future timelike infinity is up and the past timelike infinity is down in the pen rose diagram.

Comment: @SG8 - This resolution is discussed in Caroll's "Spacetime and Geometry" chapter 6. In my edition page 252, under equation 6.44, soon after he has introduced the Komar integral.

Comment: @Shashaank remember $t$ is just a coordinate. Kruskal time $T$, unlike Schwarzschild time $t$, does point upwards on the whole diagram. The $\partial_t$ is not a global notion of time. It is actually a lot like the boost Killing vector in Minkowski space.

Comment: Thanks. But, I read in Carroll's book: "If we think about the structure of the maximally extended 
Schwarzschild solution, we realize that we could draw two kinds of spacelike 
slices: those that extend through the wormhole to the second asymptotic region, 
and those that end on the singularity. If the slice extends through the wormhole, 
the other asymptotic region provides another component to a , and thus another 
contribution to (6.38); this contribution would exactly cancel, so the total energy 
would indeed be zero ..."

Comment: "... If the slice intersected the singularity, we wouldn't know 
quite how to deal with it. Nevertheless, in either case it is sensible to treat our 
result (6.44) [the Komar mass from the surface integral] as the correct answer. "            So, I suspect ... I think that the problem even with this proposal has not been solved yet!

Comment: @user1379857 1) but for the other region is the black hole horizon the future horizon or the white hole horizon the future horizon. For the black hole horizon I have t=-infty and for white hole one I have t=infty....do I use the Kruskal time or Schwarzschild time to decide which is the future horizon...2) in your first comment you just meant in nutshell that t isn’t a good coordinate in that other patch to depend on and have a notion of future or past, right..

Comment: @user1379857 which of $t$ or $T$ should I check to decide which is the future horizon and which is the past horizon

Answer (score -1):

You have simply used a wrong definition of Komar mass, please read Poisson carefully, sec.5.5.3.

1. The Komar mass is an integral over a closed 2-surface at infinity;
2. It can be separated into two parts, one is a surface integral over the horizon; the other is a volume integral, which is written in your question, see eq.(5.102).
3. You simply miss the first part $M_H$ in eq.(5.102), which gives exactly the black hole mass.
4. The part, written by you, has no contribution to Komar mass, because energy-momentum tensor is zero for vacuum.